# Error creating bean "sessionFactory"

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory, spring-bean

When I was starting Weblogic(using jar: hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar with hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar), met these error info below:

1. Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory;
2. nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
3. nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

servelet-context.xml:
        
    
        
        
            resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>             
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>             
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>        
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use.query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>      
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>
```

Below is my console info:

```
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:49 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 21 17:17:49 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/C:/Development/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/autodeploy/shop-leveling/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:50 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:51 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
Apr 21, 2015 5:17:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoadDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1799)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3041)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1374)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:452)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:629)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:40)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:196)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:339)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:427)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 61 more
<Apr 21, 2015 5:17:51 PM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoadDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoadDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nscorp.lars.shopleveling.core.dao.impl.DataLoadDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 21, 2015 5:17:51 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application '_appsdir_shop-leveling_dir'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:452)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: Post your spring configuration file.

Comment: Which version of JPA are you using , should be 2.1 or above?

Comment: @user3814298 Pls consider below jars

`Hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`

`hibernate-4.3.5.Final.jar` -- can be whatever 4.3.x

`javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar`

Comment: @ankur-singhal Thanks, jpa and hibernate.core have no problem. I am missing javax. But still get can't locate log4j error.

Comment: @user3814298 better re-deploy, close this question and ask again posting new errors

Answer (score 1):

Use **hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final** and in localhost with Tomcat I start well but when I deploy in WL i had the same error.

Adding this to the file **weblogic-application.xml** was the solution for me:

```
<prefer-application-packages>

        <!-- jpa -->
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.criteria.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.metamodel.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.spi.*</package-name>

</prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls consider below jars

```
Hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

hibernate-4.3.5.Final.jar -- can be whatever 4.3.x

javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
```